# How do I record video to internal storage?

Tags: android, video, storage, internal

I ran into a problem when my test phone recorded video and did not have a external sd-card. i get recording errors because:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
```

points to the external sd-card and since the external sd does not exist, the phone is not smart enough to point to the internal storage.

1. Is there a solution to this issue?
2. If not, how do I record directly to the internal storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test whether an SD card exists or not, read the [documentation on Environment.getExternalStorageState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29). This includes code that demonstrates how to test if the SD card is mounted, readable and / or writable. It even registers a BroadcastReceiver should the card be removed while your app in running.

From this you can divert the saved file to internal storage whenever the SD card is not viable.

**Addition from comment**

You don't provide any detail on how you are currently testing the availability of the SD card, so I've generalized the process.

```
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
...

String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + "/video.mp4");
else
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/video.mp4");
```

Comment: Yes, i have read this documentation and have implemented it, but i am still unsure as to how to divert recording to internal storage

Answer (score -1):

Try this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

You essentially want to call `openFileOutput(String fileName, MODE_PRIVATE)`. This will return a `FileOutputStream` for your use. Call `write()` to write to the file and then call `close()` to clean things up. Note that `MODE_PRIVATE` will make the file private to your application.

Comment: I know the code sample is very basic, but you should be able to adapt video recording to this procedure.

Comment: this was the direction i was leaning towards. I am still not sure how to adapt recorder to output to the FileOutputStream though...

Comment: I don't know much about video, but how are you capturing the video file? Can you call `getBytes()` on it?